# pandas time zone infer_dst doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, timezone-offset

I am using `tz_localize` to make my `index` aware in pandas. It is inferring a daylight savings time, so that 'US/Eastern' returns -04:00 when it should return -05:00. I have tried setting `infer_dst` to `false` but it does not change!

I am doing,

```
df.index = df.index.tz_localize('US/Eastern',infer_dst=False).tz_convert('UTC')
```

and ending up with a 1-hour offset.

**Is there a way to force pandas to use EST instead of EDT?**

I am new to pandas and python so please try and be explicit, that will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this?

```
In [25]: date_range('20130305',periods=10).tz_localize('US/Eastern')
Out[25]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-03-05 00:00:00-05:00, ..., 2013-03-14 00:00:00-04:00]
Length: 10, Freq: D, Timezone: US/Eastern

In [26]: date_range('20130305',periods=10).tz_localize('EST')
Out[26]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-03-05 00:00:00-05:00, ..., 2013-03-14 00:00:00-05:00]
Length: 10, Freq: D, Timezone: EST
```

`infer_dst` is a very specialized usecase that has to do with figuring out if a UTC timeseries crosses a dst transition